# MvvmCross-AndroidSupport fragment back navigation is slow

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvmcross

I’m using the MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity with a single fragment for every screen. During normal navigation the next view/fragment loads within an acceptable time-frame. When I use back navigation to a previous screen it takes much much longer.

While closing a fragment (when navigation back) I’m not doing anything, and still it takes over 2 or 3 seconds. I expected back navigation to be faster than normal navigation because views and viewmodels are already cached. The only thing it needs to do is invoke OnCreate again on the old view, while sometimes my OnCreate is almost empty and even then the delay is also noticeable.

Anyone got the same behaviour with fragments in mvvmcross 4, or has anyone tips how to approach this?

Comment: Dunno if you got time for this, but if you can make a seperate project to reproduce this and put it onto the mvvmcross github, iam sure someone will look into it.
Atleast i dont remember having long transitions when navigating back in my application.

Comment: OK, ill try to create an example project